# How can I use GitHub Actions to update a .csv file within a repo?

Tags: python, github, yaml, github-actions

I am trying to build an app that involves updating a dataset every X days. I know that you can schedule automation in GitHub Actions with YAML, but I don't know how to write the code so that the files I download (using Selenium and API calls via Python) will go straight to GitHub, rather than my personal computer. I have no experience with either YAML or GitHub Actions, so I was hoping to get some guidance on where to start.

Here is an example of what I'm doing in Selenium, I just want the final file to go straight to a repo instead of my downloads folder.

```
today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")


driver.get("https://acleddata.com/data-export-tool/")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "key").send_keys("[api key]")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "email").send_keys(r"[my email]")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "event_date_from").send_keys(r"01/11/2020")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "event_date_to").send_keys(d1)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "country_typing").send_keys("Ethiopia")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@data-check='mc-ethiopia']").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Accept']").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Export']").click()
```

Comment: What about downloading it normally and then copying it from the download folder to the local repo, committing and pushing it?

Comment: I would like the app to be fully automated without my needing to re-commit, i.e. would do all of that for me

Comment: The CI script can do that (downloading, copying, comitting)